# Doctrine UUID data type: works perfect manually but fails in Codeception

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, uuid, codeception

I’m building an Api Platform application in which User entity most likely has no email, username or any other human-readable identity. That is why I decided to use UUID-typed field as username (`User::getUsername()`). I installed `ramsey/uuid-doctrine` package and apply UUID Doctrine data type  both for `id` property and `uuid`. Removed `User::setUsername()` method since we must assign it only once while creating new User instance. Now creating new User through API works perfect both in Swagger UI and manually with REST-client. But when I try to run simplest Codeception cest, executing $I->haveInRepository it throws

```
1) UserCest: Test creating user
 Test  tests/functional/UserCest.php:createUser

  [Doctrine\Common\Persistence\Mapping\MappingException] The class 'Ramsey\Uuid\Uuid' was not found in the chain configured namespaces App\Entity


Scenario Steps:

 1. $I->haveInRepository("App\\Entity\\User") at tests/functional/UserCest.php:17

#1  /Users/erop/Developer/temp/uuid-test/vendor/doctrine/persistence/lib/Doctrine/Common/Persistence/Mapping/MappingException.php:22
#2  /Users/erop/Developer/temp/uuid-test/vendor/doctrine/persistence/lib/Doctrine/Common/Persistence/Mapping/Driver/MappingDriverChain.php:87
#3  /Users/erop/Developer/temp/uuid-test/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Mapping/ClassMetadataFactory.php:151
#4  /Users/erop/Developer/temp/uuid-test/vendor/doctrine/persistence/lib/Doctrine/Common/Persistence/Mapping/AbstractClassMetadataFactory.php:304
#5  /Users/erop/Developer/temp/uuid-test/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Mapping/ClassMetadataFactory.php:78
#6  /Users/erop/Developer/temp/uuid-test/vendor/doctrine/persistence/lib/Doctrine/Common/Persistence/Mapping/AbstractClassMetadataFactory.php:183
#7  /Users/erop/Developer/temp/uuid-test/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/EntityManager.php:283
#8  Codeception\Module\Doctrine2->haveInRepository
#9  /Users/erop/Developer/temp/uuid-test/tests/_support/_generated/FunctionalTesterActions.php:2792
#10 /Users/erop/Developer/temp/uuid-test/tests/functional/UserCest.php:17
```

Have no idea what and where should I tune up something to make test working. What I found on Internet mostly relate to relationship of entities in different bundles. But as you can see this is not the case. Any ideas how to fix the issue?

Comment: Not familiar with codeception.  The error message implies that the ramsey package never got installed.  Does codeception use composer.json to install dependencies?  If so, is the ramsey package listed in composer.json?

Comment: @Cerad, ramsey' package installed, everything's working fine. I mean creating User through Swagger UI. All imports OK. No problem with code at all. The problem appears when Codeception starts executing `$I->haveInRepository($user)`. Then Doctrine starts collecting class metadata, etc. and fails. My question is why and what should "be tuned up" to solve the problem.

Comment: From Codeception point of view, this is an issue of Doctrine.

Comment: I see, @Naktibalda. Looks like it's gonna be a long long day digging into Doctrine guts. Thanks!

Comment: @Naktibalda, looks like the disaster starts here https://github.com/Codeception/Codeception/blob/3.1/src/Codeception/Module/Doctrine2.php#L1034 when `User::$id` being instance of `Ramsey\Uuid\Uuid` is used for further extracting its PK. Does it make sense in discussed context?

Comment: Try downgrading Codeception to 3.1.0

Comment: Yes, it works on 3.1.0! Thank you, @Naktibalda

Comment: Please raise an issue at https://github.com/Codeception/Codeception/issues

Comment: @Naktibalda, is this good enough https://github.com/Codeception/Codeception/issues/5691 ?